# Post JQuery variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

So I have this select field:

```
        <select name="year" id = "year" class="dropdown-select">
            <option value="2005">All Years</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
        </select>
```

And I have this jquery to get the selected value any time a new value is selected:

```
$("#year").change(function() {
    input_year =  parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

My question is how would I go about posting the 'input_year' variable to PHP every time the value changes?

The end goal is to do something with $_POST['year'] in PHP and return the result to JavaScript e.g `echo "var res = " . $_POST['year'] . ";";`

Comment: you tagged it yourself, using `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple implementation

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'your_url.php',
    data:'input_year='+input_year,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

data string may need a `?` before it, I can't remember off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX, specifically the jQuery [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function:

```
$("#year").change(function() {
    input_year =  parseInt($(this).val());
    $.post('/path/to/file', year: input_year, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        /*optional stuff to do after success */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#year").change(function() {
    var input_year =  parseInt($(this).val());

    $.post('server.php',{year:input_year}, function(result,status){});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ajax`. With `jquery`, it would be like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'text',
   url: "(your php filename)",
   data: $.param({'year': input_year}),
   success:function(data){
      //do whatever you need to do with the received result
   }
   error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert(request.responseText);
   }
});
```